# Appending struct onto Struct Array in Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I have a Struct:

```
struct Note{
    var date: String;
    var comment: String;
}
```

Then I create a an array with two arrays nested within,

```
var data = [[Note()],[Contributors()]]
```

These two arrays are used to populate two sections of a Table View. 
I need to append a struct onto the Notes struct array but when I try and append it using

```
data[0].append(Note(date: "06-06-2012",comment:"Created Note"))
```

and

```
(data[0] as! Note).append(Note(date: "06-06-2012",comment:"Created Note"))
```

throws the error

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value of type 'Note'

How you can mutate values that need to be casted?

Comment: You need to append not a new `Note` AND `Contributors` (based on my testing) - `data.append([Note(data: "06-06-2012",comment:"Created Note"), [Contributors()]]` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial creation of the arrays is incorrect.

Change:

```
var data = [[Note()],[Contributors()]]
```

to:

```
var data: [Any] = [[Note](),[Contributors]()]
```

Your code creates an array that contains at index 0 an array of `Any` that contains one empty `Note` instance and at index 1 an array of `Any` that contains one empty `Contributors` instance.

The fix creates an array that contains an empty `Note` array at index 0 and an empty `Contributors` array at index 1.

But even with all of those "fixes", you still get the error if you do:

```
(data[0] as! Note).append(Note(date: "06-06-2012",comment:"Created Note"))
```

It's kind of strange to have `data` contain two different types of data. You really should have two arrays:

```
var notes = [Note]()
var contributors = [Contributors]()
```

Then you can easily do:

```
notes.append(Note(date: "06-06-2012",comment:"Created Note"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have solution by using `protocol`

```
protocol DataSourceNoteContributors {}

struct Contributors: DataSourceNoteContributors{

}
struct Note:DataSourceNoteContributors{
    var date: String;
    var comment: String;
}
```

Then can be used easly

```
    var data = [Note(date: "date", comment: "comment"),Contributors()]

    data.append(Note(date: "note1", comment: "comment2"))
    data.append(Contributors())
```

// using cast to recognize

```
if data[0] as Note {

}
```